# Search for the nearest array in a huge array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, word2vec

I need to find the closest possible sentence.
I have an array of sentences and a user sentence, and I need to find the closest to the user's sentence element of the array.

I presented each sentence in the form of a vector using word2vec:

```
def get_avg_vector(word_list, model_w2v, size=500):
    sum_vec = np.zeros(shape = (1, size))
    count = 0

    for w in word_list:
        if w in model_w2v and w != '':
            sum_vec += model_w2v[w]
            count +=1
    if count == 0:
        return sum_vec
    else:
        return sum_vec / count + 1
```

As a result, the array element looks like this:

```
array([[ 0.93162371,  0.95618944,  0.98519795,  0.98580566,  0.96563747,
         0.97070891,  0.99079191,  1.01572807,  1.00631016,  1.07349398,
         1.02079309,  1.0064849 ,  0.99179418,  1.02865136,  1.02610303,
         1.02909719,  0.99350413,  0.97481178,  0.97980362,  0.98068508,
         1.05657591,  0.97224562,  0.99778703,  0.97888296,  1.01650529,
         1.0421448 ,  0.98731804,  0.98349052,  0.93752996,  0.98205837,
         1.05691232,  0.99914532,  1.02040555,  0.99427229,  1.01193818,
         0.94922226,  0.9818139 ,  1.03955   ,  1.01252615,  1.01402485,
         ...
         0.98990598,  0.99576604,  1.0903802 ,  1.02493086,  0.97395976,
         0.95563786,  1.00538653,  1.0036294 ,  0.97220088,  1.04822631,
         1.02806122,  0.95402776,  1.0048053 ,  0.97677222,  0.97830801]])
```

I represent the sentence of the user also as a vector, and I compute the closest element to it is like this:

```
%%cython
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

def compute_dist(v, list_sentences):
    dist_dict = {}

    for key, val in list_sentences.items():
        dist_dict[key] = euclidean(v, val)

    return sorted(dist_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0]
```

`list_sentences` in the method above is a dictionary in which keys are a text representation of sentences, and values are vector.

It takes a very long time, because I have more than 60 million sentences.
How can I speed up, optimize this process?

I'll be grateful for any advice.

Comment: What you're asking for is related to the nearest neighbor problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Linear_search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial calculation of the 60 million sentences' vectors is essentially a fixed cost you'll pay once. I'm assuming you mainly care about the time for each subsequent lookup, for a single user-supplied query sentence.

Using numpy native array operations can speed up the distance calculations over doing your own individual calculations in a Python loop. (It's able to do things in bulk using its optimized code.)

But first you'd want to replace `list_sentences` with a true numpy array, accessed only by array-index. (If you have other keys/texts you need to associate with each slot, you'd do that elsewhere, with some dict or list.)

Let's assume you've done that, in whatever way is natural for your data, and now have `array_sentences`, a 60-million by 500-dimension numpy array, with one sentence average vector per row.

Then a 1-liner way to get an array full of the distances is as the vector-length ("norm") of the difference between each of the 60 million candidates and the 1 query (which gives a 60-million entry answer with each of the differences):

```
dists = np.linalg.norm(array_sentences - v)
```

Another 1-liner way is to use the numpy utility function `cdist()` for comuting distance between each pair of two collections of inputs. Here, your first collection is just the one query vector `v` (but if you had batches to do at once, supplying more than one query at a time could offer an additional slight speedup):

```
dists = np.linalg.cdists(array[v], array_sentences)
```

(Note that such vector comparisons often use cosine-distance/cosine-similarity rather than euclidean-distance. If you switch to that, you might be doing other norming/dot-products instead of the first option above, or use the `metric='cosine'` option to `cdist()`.)

Once you have all the distances in a numpy array, using a numpy-native sort option is likely to be faster than using Python `sorted()`. For example, numpy's indirect sort `argsort()`, which just returns the sorted indexes (and thus avoids moving all the vector coordinates-around), since you just want to know *which* items are the best match(es). For example:

```
sorted_indexes = argsort(dists)
best_index = sorted_indexes[0]
```

If you need to turn that int index back into your other key/text, you'd use your own dict/list that remembered the slot-to-key relationships.

All these still give an exactly right result, by comparing against all candidates, which (even when done optimally well) is still time-consuming.

There are ways to get faster results, based on pre-building indexes to the full set of candidates – but such indexes become very tricky in high-dimensional spaces (like your 500-dimensional space). They often trade off perfectly accurate results for faster results. (That is, what they return for 'closest 1' or 'closest N' will have some errors, but usually not be off by much.) For examples of such libraries, see [Spotify's ANNOY](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) or [Facebook's FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss).

Answer (score 2):

At least if you are doing this procedure for multiple sentences, you could try using `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` (I don't know whether it pays for itself on a single query. Also `500` is quite high, I seem to remember KDTrees work better for not quite as many dimensions. You'll have to experiment).

Assuming you've put all your vectors (dict values) into one large numpy array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
>>>
# 100,000 vectors (that's all my RAM can take)
>>> a = np.random.random((100000, 500))
>>>
>>> t = KDTree(a)
# create one new vector and find distance and index of closest
>>> t.query(np.random.random(500))
(8.20910072933986, 83407)
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think about 2 possible ways of optimizing this process.

First, if your goal is only to get the closest vector (or sentence), you could get rid of the `list_sentences` variable and only keep in memory the closest sentence you have found yet. This way, you won't need to sort the complete (and presumably very large) list at the end, and only return the closest one.

```
def compute_dist(v, list_sentences):
    min_dist = 0

    for key, val in list_sentences.items():
        dist = euclidean(v, val)
        if dist < min_dist:
            closest_sentence = key
            min_dist = dist

    return closest_sentence
```

The second one is maybe a little more unsound. You can try to re implement the `euclidean` method by giving it a third argument which would be the current minimum distance `min_dist` between the closest vector you have found so far and the user vector. I don't know how the scipy `euclidean` method is implemented but I guess it is close to summing squared differences along all the vectors dimensions. What you want is the method to stop if the sum is higher than `min_dist` (the distance will be higher than `min_dist` anyway and you won't keep it).